# iOS Auto renewable Subscription receipt format

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Can anyone help me to find the difference between Latest_Receipt_Info and Receipt in the json response of valid receipt? Here is a sample response what I get it. I am not understanding that why there are 2 dictionaries of the receipt form which has same information..

```
  "latest_receipt_info" =     {
    bid = abc;
    bvrs = "1.0.1";
    "expires_date" = 1441188719000;
    "expires_date_formatted" = "2015-09-02 10:11:59 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_formatted_pst" = "2015-09-02 03:11:59 America/Los_Angeles";
    "item_id" = 123456789;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2015-08-11 05:42:32 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1439271752000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2015-08-10 22:42:32 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 100000012346;
    "product_id" = "com.abc.xyz";
    "purchase_date" = "2015-09-02 10:08:59 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1441188539000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2015-09-02 03:08:59 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 1000000123456;
    "unique_identifier" = 123bc123abc123acb123asd;
    "unique_vendor_identifier" = "4gat5s-as4b5h-h4fkk4-k2i8ds";
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000030396244;
};
receipt =     {
    bid = abc;
    bvrs = "1.0.1";
    "expires_date" = 1441188719761;
    "expires_date_formatted" = "2015-09-02 10:11:59 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_formatted_pst" = "2015-09-02 03:11:59 America/Los_Angeles";
    "item_id" = 123456789;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2015-08-11 05:42:32 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1439271752000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2015-08-10 22:42:32 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000123344;
    "product_id" = "com.abc.xyz";
    "purchase_date" = "2015-09-02 10:08:59 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1441188539761;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2015-09-02 03:08:59 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 100000012334455;
    "unique_identifier" = 123bc123abc123acb123asd;
    "unique_vendor_identifier" = "4gat5s-as4b5h-h4fkk4-k2i8ds";
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000030123344;
};
status = 0;
```

}

Comment: When you make more transactions `latest receipt` will show the latest receipt as expected,  and `receip`t will show historic transactions

Comment: But in the mentioned receipt there is no difference at all

Comment: Because you don't have any historic transactions so the current and historic transaction will be the same.  Make another purchase